# Is there a way to exclude fields from a TypeORM relations (or include certain fields)

Tags: typescript, orm, typeorm

I have some OneToMany and ManyToOne relationships defined in my TypeORM, which are working as expected; within my find I can select certain columns from the original table with the 'select statement thus::

```
  return await this.namedRepository.find({
    select: ["ua_id", "ua_linkid_agent", "ua_linkid_usr"],
    where: { ua_linkid_usr: usr_id },
    relations: ["ua_agent"],
```

Is there a way to limit the fields coming back from the array in "ua_agent", (for example "ua_id" and "ua_status") without having to resort to the `select:false` criteria on all the other `@Column()`s in the entity file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it using querybuilder as followes

```
this.namedRepository.createQueryBuilder('your_entity')
    .leftJoinAndSelect('your_entity.ua_agent', 'ua_agent')
    .select(['ua_id', 'ua_status', 'ua_agent.whatevercolumn'])
    .getMany()
```

with querybuilder you can select only what you need.

Comment: Thank you - took me a bit of time to figure out the correct syntax, but this does indeed grab only the fields required from the joined table!

Comment: this is one of the most ts orm libraries and doesn't have an exclude function

Answer (score 1):

Given a `UserEntity` like

```js
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, BeforeInsert, OneToMany } from "typeorm";
import { UserRole } from "./users.enum";
import { hash, compare } from "bcryptjs";
import { PostEntity } from "src/posts/posts.entity";

@Entity("users")
export class UserEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
  public id: string;

  @Column({
    unique: true,
    type: "varchar",
    length: 50,
    nullable: false
  })
  public email: string;

  @Column({
    type: "char",
    length: 60,
    nullable: false
  })
  public password: string;

  @Column({
    type: "enum",
    enum: UserRole,
    nullable: false
  })
  public role: UserRole;

  @OneToMany(() => PostEntity, (post: PostEntity) => post.author)
  public posts: Array<PostEntity>;

  @BeforeInsert()
  public async hashPassword() {
    this.password = await hash(this.password, 10);
  }

  public isValidPassword(password: string) {
    return compare(password, this.password);
  }
}
```

And a `PostEntity` like

```js
import { UserEntity } from "src/users/users.entity";
import { Column, Entity, ManyToOne, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";

@Entity("posts")
export class PostEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
  public id: string;

  @Column({
    type: "varchar",
    length: 50,
    unique: true,
    nullable: false
  })
  public title: string;

  @Column({
    type: "text",
    nullable: false
  })
  public body: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => UserEntity, (author: UserEntity) => author.posts)
  public author: UserEntity;
}
```

You can use the `select` property in the `find` method to select deep nested properties in relationships as follow.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { PostEntity } from './posts.entity';

@Injectable()
export class PostsService {
  public constructor(@InjectRepository(PostEntity) private readonly postRepository: Repository<PostEntity>) { }

  public getPosts() {
    return this.postRepository.find({
      relations: ["author"],
      select: {
        id: true,
        title: true,
        body: true,
        author: {
          email: true
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

This way, you can easily use the Repository Pattern and still have the ability to omit certain fields, even in relationships for security purposes for instance.